# Can I get a T-shirt by donating Tor $75 via cryptocurrency?

Tags: help

Recently, I donated Tor $25 via Bitcoin, but then I realized that they’re running a campaign that they will give people who donated $75 or more a T-shirt. Just wondering if I can send them $50 more and get a T-shirt.

Answer (score 0):

You should send them an email and ask. It may take them a few days to reply as they get a lot of email.

See https://www.torproject.org/contact/

> For questions and comments about Tor the non-profit organization: trademark questions, affiliation and coordination, contract inquiries, etc, please email frontdesk[at]torproject.org. **For donor-related questions, contact giving[at]torproject.org.**